# Exposing meta data for a WCF 4.0 Rest Template Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-client, wcf-rest

Probably missing something very basic. I created a WCF 4.0 Rest Service. It works no problems when I'm hitting the url from a browser and I'm getting back what I want.

But now I want to use that service from a client mvc application (it will also be used by other non .net platforms which is why it's a rest service in the first place).

Problem is how do I get a service reference to it so I can start to use it in my c# code? With the new minimal WCF .net 4 config approach and no interface for the service contract, I don't know how to specify a mex endpoint. Ultimately I don't want a mex endpoint in production, just during development. I would love to be able to specify that all my services (around 10 in one application) have endpoints with one tiny piece of config that vs2010 .config transformations just rips out when I publish.

Answer (score 14):

[Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/magazine/dd942839%28en-us%29.aspx#id0070024). REST service doesn't use metadata. Metadata (Mex endpoint) are only for SOAP services because WSDL 1.1 (the only [version supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730294.aspx) by WCF) is able to describe only SOAP service. [WADL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) or WSDL 2.0 is able to describe REST service but non of them is currently supported by WCF.

REST service is consumed by using `WebRequest` directly or by building `ChannelFactory` on top of shared contracts. Both methods are described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/04/21/how-to-consume-rest-services-with-wcf.aspx). Other method is to use `HttpClient` from [REST Starter kit](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644) (former API). The problem with Starter kit is that it has never reached RTM (it was replaced by WCF 4). Instead of metadata endpoint WCF 4 REST service offers [help page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/11/clients-and-the-automatic-help-page-in-wcf-webhttp-services.aspx) where all operation are described. When using WCF 4 REST template the help page should be already turned on - just add /help sufix to address of your service. [Here is another article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/magazine/ee309509%28en-us%29.aspx) about building REST clients.

Comment: Thanks, since I posted I've watched and read many articles. The part where I'm a bit confused is that everyone uses WCF Data Services by hitting urls (isn't that REST?) and then generates a client from the by Add Service Reference.

Comment: But as I know it is a feature of WCF Data Services.